# Select the vertex of a path closest to another object with geometry nodes

Tags: vertices, geometry-nodes

So, let's say I have a straight path with 5 vertices and a sphere in my scene. What I want to do is to animate the position of my sphere and, through geometry nodes, select the closest vertex of the path to the sphere. Would that be possible ?

My complete idea and project is to have a 3D grid which scales proportionally to an object's location, with the scaling being local to the vertex.
I'm basically trying to have a working model of this animation: https://youtu.be/DYq774z4dws?t=265

I don't have much experience in geometry nodes, so my request may be impossible or hard to do, but I'm willing to put in the work to understand that :)) (I'm a student in physics, so if any maths explanations are required for me to understand, I should be fine)

Thank you !!

Comment: i think you could easily achieve this by using geometry proximity node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this animation, I think all you're interested in is the position of the target sphere, not its surface. This way just uses a common input parameter both to set the position of the target, and to tell the grid where it is.

The warp of the grid is a mix between the point-positions in the grid, and the position of the target, as a function of the distance between the points and the target...

[image]

You could, instead, bring the target in as an outside Object Info, if you wanted, and use its Position output...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey ! Sorry I forgot to answer this comment the last two weeks, but I tried it and it worked perfectly ! I could add a few changes as I liked, there were a few nodes I wasn't sure what they did but I looked it up and understood them. However, I'm not exactly clear on what you did concerning the panel "Set position to mix between Position and f(Distance to target), could you elaborate a bit more on the logic you used for that ? And exactly is the maths in there ?

Thank you for your answer and consideration !

Comment: @aidegare No problem!  The _Mix_ is a linear interpolation between the point's own position (Fac == 0) and the position of the target (Fac ==1).  Fac is determined by some function of the distance between the undeformed point and the target. In this illustration, Fac is set to `1/( point->target distance) squared`, put through a smoothing function in _Map Range_ . It was determined purely aesthetically, and as an imitation of your reference, not as any attempt to represent genuine GR curvature ( which would have had to include the `t` of `txyz` spacetime anyway ..  8-\  .. )